# Example of a power series whose radius of convergence is 0

Tags: complex-analysis

What is an example of a power series whose radius of convergence is 0? Thank you for any help as I need this to study.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!z^n$ is an example

Comment: thank you! @FoobazJohn